# C++ - Separate declaration/definition for template function in template class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, methods, implementation

I am aware that the syntax for declaring a template class method in a header and defining it in a source file goes as so:

myclass.h

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
  public:
    void method(T input);
  private:
    T privVar;
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::method(T input) {
    privVar = input;
}
```

But, what if the method is also a template?
I am adding methods to the `basic_string` class, and I want to know how to write the implementation for the functions.

MyString.h

```
template <class _Elem   = TCHAR,
          class _Traits = std::char_traits<_Elem>,
          class _Ax     = std::allocator<_Elem>>
class String
    : public std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax> {
  private:
    // Types for the conversion operators.
    typedef       _Elem* _StrTy;
    typedef const _Elem* _ConstStrTy;

    //...

  public:
        // Conversion operators so 'String' can easily be
        // assigned to a C-String without calling 'c_str()'.
    operator _StrTy() const {
        return const_cast<_StrTy>(this->c_str());
    }

    operator _ConstStrTy() const {
        return this->c_str();
    }

    // ... Constructors ...

    /*------------ Additional Methods ------------*/

    //! Converts a value of the given type to a string.
    template <class _ValTy> static String ConvertFrom(_ValTy val);

    //! Converts a string to the given type.
    template <class _ValTy> static _ValTy ConvertTo(const String& str);
    template <class _ValTy> _ValTy ConvertTo(void) const;

    //! Checks if a string is empty or is whitespace.
    static bool IsNullOrSpace(const String& str);
    bool IsNullOrSpace(void) const;

    //! Converts a string to all upper-case.
    static String ToUpper(String str);
    void ToUpper(void);

    // ...
};
```

How could I implement `template <class _ValTy> static String ConvertFrom(_ValTy val);`? Because now not only do I need to specify the class template, but the function template too. I am betting the code I'm about to write isn't valid, but it should show what I am trying to accomplish:

MyString.cpp

```
template <class _Elem, class _Traits, class _Ax>
template <class _ValTy>
String<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax> String<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax>::ConvertFrom(_ValTy val) {
    // Convert value to String and return it...
}
```

I am not advanced at all with templates. Not only am I very doubtful that the above is valid, it seems cumbersome to write and not very readable. How would I go about implementing the template methods, and the static template methods which returns its own class type? Because I don't want to define them in the header.

Comment: You should probably read: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: @JesseGood That shows me that there IS a way to implement a *normal* method from a template class in a source file separately, but not how to implement *templated* methods from a template class. Maybe I am overlooking something in the post, I don't want to be THAT guy. Should I just give up and go ahead and define the class methods inline in the header file?

Comment: If you are just trying to separate out prototypes from functionality for templates functions/classes you can try using the .inl paradigm: where the actual functionality is the .inl file, and you include that file at the end of your header file.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: When you say `inline in the header file`, do you mean inside the class? This is not the case, you can define template members outside the class in the header file or a separate implementation file, just **not** in a source file (only except if you explicitly instantiate them).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before I answer your question, let me first say: Don't do this. Extend `std::string` by using free-functions instead, much like the standard library implements many algorithms. Additionally I'd suggest doing it for ranges rather than `string`s only but that's more subjective.

Also note that `std::string` avoids implicit conversions to C-strings not to make your life harder, but to protect your code from a wide variety of obscure bugs that can be caused by unexpected implicit conversions. I would think very long and hard about implementing them. Just think about this: It takes you a few extra moments to type`.c_str()` once when you write the code, and for the rest of eternity anyone who reads your code will immediately know that it's being used as a C-style string and not as a `std::string`.

To answer your question, just put the code in the header:

```
//! Converts a value of the given type to a string.
template <class _ValTy> static String ConvertFrom(_ValTy val)
{
    // Code here
}
```

Finally note that identifiers starting with underscore+capital letter (and many other things starting with `_`) are reserved for the compiler and thus all bets are off as to your program's functionality.

Answer (score 23):

Syntax of definition of template member functions outside of template is like this:

```
template <class T> struct A
{
   template <class X> void f();
};

template<class T> template<class X> void A<T>::f()
{
}
```

So your code is correct.

Would like to note that defining template members in `.cpp` is not very useful. In this case you shall explicitly instantiate them with all types you need to use with this template. Or do not use them outside this `.cpp` which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your function definition is valid, and it can't be defined outside of the class declaration in a less verbose way.  Since you want to put the function definition in a .cpp file you can't take advantage of combining the function definition with the more concise function declaration.  By putting the function definition in a .cpp file you will also have to explicitly instantiate all needed specializations of your template class.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an attempt to make an example code for Rost and Josh's answers:

template.hpp

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
class Add
{
public:
    T Addition(T summand1, T summand2);
};

void AddUsing( int summand1, int summand2 );
```

template.cpp

```
#include "template.hpp"
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T Add<T>::Addition(T summand1, T summand2)
{
    return summand1 + summand2;
}

void AddUsing( int summand1, int summand2 )
{
    std::cout << Add<int>().Addition( summand1, summand2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "template.hpp"

int main()
{
    AddUsing ( 2, 2 );
}
```